# How this syntax to check the request format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For my rails API, I need to put some code as blow to make post request successfully.(I google it).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception 
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
end
```

My question is, how "c.request.format" know the format is json or not?
Where did it check?Something relate to Proc.new??

Comment: you have to check the 'Content-Type' in [request headers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers).

Comment: FYI, you can now use: `request.format.json #=> false` and `request.format.html? #=> true`, etc. _At least in Rails 5.2+._

Answer (score 8):

try something like:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: :json_request?

protected

def json_request?
  request.format.json?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for better method. Now I know there is a request object under action controller so we can use it, right?

Comment: FYI, this is already built into Rails (5.2 at least) so you can go: `request.format.json #=> false` and `request.format.html? #=> true`, etc.